# How could I implement this neural network in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r

In [Establishing, versus maintaining, brain function: a neurocomputational model of cortical reorganisation after injury to the immature brain](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1112/1112.5463.pdf), Varier et al develop a neural network model of motor control and then "lesion" it as it is training. I am new to neural networks and really do not even know where to begin in emulating them so that I can investigate this further for myself. Any hints would be appreciated. The details of the model can be found on page 16 of the linked arxiv paper.

**Figure 1 from the linked paper:**
[image]

Comment: This question shows a lack of pre-work—you're basically asking us to do all the work for you in setting up this problem with R. You need to ask a more precise question if you want to elicit useful feedback.

Comment: @aeismail Yes, as I mentioned I really have no idea how to go about doing this. Chicken and egg problem. Even if the answer is that not enough information was provided by the paper authors, that would be good.

Comment: You have to learn how to crawl before you can walk. Try implementing _any neural network_ model first. There must be models a lot simpler than this available. Then try adding the complexity that allows you to reproduce this model. In general, it shouldn't be based exclusively on figures. There needs to be some text explaining the model!

Comment: @aeismail The text description is on page 16 as I mentioned. I did not copy/paste it here because I do not understand how to format the equations. Also, I suppose you are right that what I need is a simple custom neural network written in R.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are two considerable packages in **R** to handle neural networks with easiness. Here they are: `nnet` and `neuralnet`.

Install them via

> install.packages('nnet')
>
> install.packages('neuralnet')

in **R**. To get help and see examples, see

> ?neuralnet::neuralnet
>
> ?nnet::nnet

You can look at a neural network as a function `f(x)` where `x` is a vector of inputs. You put a vector and the neural network answers you a number.

The first two problems you will find are

- **Define an architecture**. For simplicity, take a single node at first, this will be equal to a linear regression.
- **Train the network**. There are algorithms such as Levenberg-Marquardt.

This is the absolute minimum you have to know in order to program/run a neural network in **R**.

Comment: I am able to use nnet for simple classification problems but have assumed that the type of model described in the question is completely different. For example it is not clear to me what the model described is actually learning.

Comment: It's learning to approximate the answer you train it. Imagine you have a dataset `X` which is multidimensional and a response `y` for which you want to approximate by `f(X)`, i.e., `f(X) = y + error` where `error` is what you want to minimize. Actually, you can see as `X` is trying to explain `y` via `f(X)`. The power to explain `y` depends completely on the the function `f` you choose. Take, for example, `f(X) = c1*X[1]+c2*X[2]+c3*X[3]` where `X` is tridimensional; here, you need to train the network to find the constants `c1,c2,c3`, then you'll have something like `f(X)=2X[1]+3X[2]-7X[3]`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me. But if you read page 16 of the arxiv paper I don't understand what they are using as a measure of error, if anything. Instead they appear to be iterating through different sets of weights until the system attains stability? They say 'This equation implements a Hebbian learning paradigm where synaptic weights increase if pre-synaptic and post-synaptic activity are correlated and decrease otherwise.'

Comment: Very exotic, this is new to me. Usually, what you try to minimize is the mean squared error to fit `f` to your data, `MSE(c1,c2,c3) = (1/n) * sqrt(sum((y - f(X,c1,c2,c3))^2))`.